# Как можно закрыть все подпроцессы процесса?(c#)

Tags: c#

Как можно закрывать все подпроцессы определенного процесса, например проводника?
например:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: откройте вкладку "детали" в диспетчере задач, и если там сможете найти и убить то что вам нужно не убивая то что не нужно, то решение есть, в противном случае - нет.

Comment: диспетчер задач умеет убивать подпроцессы не убивая сам процесс, но как сделать это с помощью с#?

Comment: найти id дочернего процесса и убить https://stackoverflow.com/a/2520423/12888024, https://www.derpturkey.com/c-process-tree/, https://www.programmersought.com/article/71932902858/